# Tooling issues in the portable XAML files of Xamarin mobile project (2017)

Tags: c#, xamarin

So, I'm a C++ developer poking around into C#/Xamarin (did some Silverlight back a while ago.) I'm using VS 2017, the released version. I think that the preview is acting the same.

If I try to make changes to the main (porable) project versions the XAML files, I don't get a functional form previewer, it wants to use the live viewer simulating either Android or iOS. That's a lot slower and less convenient that just previewing the layout as I go, with alignment bars and all that. I do get the form previewer if I make changes in the UWP sub-project, but of course those then don't show up.

Also, if I edit the portable XAML I get no error checking. If I edit the UWP XAML I get error checking, but that's useless for the same reason.

So that all just doesn't make sense to me. Am I missing something? Why pre-generate the dups to begin with since we shouldn't need them other than for platform specific stuff, and why do the tools not work on the ones that we have to actually use?

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/104671/what-the-difference-between-app-and-mainpage-to-implement-my-controls

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't really address the issues I posted above. Just to throw another one in, if I edit the portable XAML I get no indication of errors in the XAML, but I do in the UWP version of the XAML. So, if we are supposed to do the work in the portable one, all of this doesn't really sound so great.

Comment: Meaning, I know the reason why there would be stuff in each section, to deal with platform specific issues. But the stuff above is about tooling and why it works in the UWP stuff (which presumbly we should never use unless we have UWP specific things to do) and doesn't in the portable one, which presumably we should use.)

Comment: Nevermind. The issues seem to have been taken care of in preview 5, pretty much.

Answer (score 0):

These issues were taken care of, as best I can tell, in preview 5, though with some fiddling about. I get intellisense and error reporting in the portable (Xamarin specific I guess) Xaml files. The new live viewer isn't as nice as the UWP/Forms one that was in the tab and provided alignment and all that. Hopefully they will get that applied to the Xamarin specific XAML files.